# Is there a way to prevent user from changing the site settings/permissions?

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge

We have a compliance requirement due to which we cannot allow users to change site settings aka site permissions in the browsers either through the settings page or by clicking padlock icon in the address bar.

Is there a way to lock the settings overall or per website in anyway, even with admin policies or programmatically in javascript ?

I couldn't find any information reading documentation. Thank you.

Comment: This requirement is not logical... what's the purpose?

Comment: Are you using corporate devices? is. this for an intranet application?

Comment: @MiguelSuazo yes, its corporate devices and intranet application (Not accessible from outside the organization).

Comment: @CherryDT Compliance ask, i honestly don't want to deal with that team with further questions

Comment: Hm then this is pretty much a dead end. It sounds like an XY problem. If there is a security aspect here, it's probably something the Intranet application would need to handle, but to help with how, we'd need to understand the real goal here.

Comment: I searched the Microsoft Edge related group policy, but did not find the site settings related settings, so I think this is impossible.

Comment: @XudongPeng, thank you very much for your reply. Could be true, i couldn't find from the documentation either.

Comment: @CherryDT, i respect your opinion and you are right in some aspect, you could have provided a better or alternative approach knowing why but as i said, for some of the intranet website that deal with federal compliance related activities with penalties, we do not want the users to modify settings like disable javascript or even location permission. Please share if you know how.

Comment: I don't know how, I just feel it's useless because for some of these aspects there are other solutions (the intranet app can detect disabled Javascript with a noscript tag and just show "please enable javascript" then, the app can also detect refused location permission and show an error, etc) and at the same time there is no way to prevent someone who _wants_ to circumvent it to actually do so, because the browser devtools could be used, or extensions, or bookmarklets with JavaScript, or even different browsers entirely, to manipulate the app. Security _cannot_ be enforced on the _client_.

Comment: I was trying to understand if there is a specific problem this is trying to solve, because in that case maybe I could have a provided a different but actually effective solution to the real problem.

Comment: The closest thing to your idea I can think of would be to not offer the application over a regular browser at all but to have users use it as desktop app via Electron. You could then check the user agent and refuse to work otherwise, or even go one step further and build an encryption mechanism with a key buried in a native module in the Electron app to make it very hard to find a way to use the application outside of the Electron app. (it's still possible, so you still need to ensure integrity and security on the _server side_ like with any web app, but it's a lot harder.)